# Compact an "if" in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I did a script with an `if` that takes several hundred lines because it lists all the possibilities, I would like to know if it is possible to reduce its size to only a few lines because I find myself lost in all these lines. Here is an example of the code:

```
if [ "$player_position" = 1 ]; then
  echo "Player is on the tile 1"
elif [ "$player_position" = 2 ]; then
  echo "Player is on the tile 2"
elif [ "$player_position" = 3 ]; then
  echo "Player is on the tile 3"
fi
```

And so on. I want to get rid all the `elif` but keep all the possibilities

PS : Each tile has a name that is in a variable like "tile_1_name" that number also has to change

Comment: Is the tile number always the exact same value as the value of `$player_position`? What is the range of valid values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of bash (4.4 I believe), you can use [a "nameref"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters)

```
# first check the bounds of the position
if (( 1 <= player_position && player_position <= max_upper_position )); then
    declare -n tile="tile_${player_position}_name"
    echo "Player is on the tile ${tile:-with no name}"
else
    echo "Invalid player position: $player_position"
fi
```

However, you should stop using "dynamic" variable names like "tile_1_name". Instead use an array:

```
tile_names[4]="Fourth tile"
...
echo "Player is on the tile ${tile_names[$player_position]:-with no name}"
```

Comment: Thanks you ! But I don't understand the array

Comment: Do you not understand the syntax or the concept of the array?

Comment: I think the both because I don't know how to set the names of the tiles, I always get "Player is on the tile with no name" :/

Comment: Currently you must do something like `tile_1_name="something"; tile_2_name="something else"; ...`. Instead of that, do `tile_names[1]="something"; tile_names[2]="something else"; ...`

Comment: I had a typo in my answer that I just fixed.

Comment: I have an other question, can I do something like this: tile_${player_position}_owner=$player_name ?

Comment: No. To do that in bash: `declare "tile_${player_position}_owner=$player_name"` -- as I mentioned, constructed variable names are harder to work with than arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
if  [ "$player_position" -ge 1 -a "$player_position" -le 3 ]; then
  echo "Player is on the tile $player_position"
fi
```

Explanation:

- `-ge`: greater than or equal
- `-le`: less than or equal
- `-a`: logical AND

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`case`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case) statement:

```
case "$player_position" in                                        
[0-9])
    echo "Player is on the tile $player_position"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to do it via cycle.
For example:

```
player_position=0
tile_1_name=0

for (( i=0; i<=100; i++ ))
do
     if [ "$player_position" == $i ];then
         echo "Player is on the tile $i"
         echo $tile_1_name
     fi
 tile_1_name+=1
 done
```

Comment: I forgot to specify that each tile has a name that is in a variable like "$ tile_1_name" that number also has to change, how can I do it? Is it possible with a for loop ?
When I try your script it gives me `Syntax error: Bad for loop variable`

Comment: I have saved correct script in my answer but I don't know where $tile_1_name need to declare.